# Replace string with a value

Tags: c#

I have a C# string as shown below. I need to give a value to `{0}`. How can I do it?

```
var valueActions = @"{
    ""Name"": {0},
}";
```

At the end what I need to see is:

```
{
    Name: James,
}
```

Comment: Are you *actually* trying to create JSON? If so, I'd strongly recommend using a JSON library instead of using string interpolation.

Comment: `string.Format`? Why are the quotes around Name missing in the result?

Comment: Both String.Format and string interpolation works. As suggested by @JonSkeet I would avoid trying to manually build JSON via direct string manipulation. Can you please offer a little more context ? What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I know I am repeating others suggestions, but let already made libraries do the hard work for you.